# Getting 80th percentile in sns.kdeplot

Tags: python, statistics, data-visualization, data-science, cdf

I am trying to use the following commands

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.kdeplot(students,cumulative = True)
```

This gives the correct kde cdf plot , but I dont know how to get the x-coordinate for y = 0.8 , 0.9 i.e 80th or 90th percentile, or any other value, in the Cumulative Distribution Function graph ( or the KDE plot) Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to add information to the plot at that point, or just calculate the percentile values? If it's the latter, then you should be able to calculate that directly from the data rather than the plot. What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)?

Comment: The 80th and 90th percentiles are  `np.percentile(students, [80, 90])`. You can calculate them more manual by sorting the array and indexing at 80% of its length.

Comment: I am trying to find the 80th and 90th percentiles using kde plot as a probability density function